# 404 on Angular assets intermittent

Tags: javascript, angular, magnolia

Our site uses Angular 7.0.0 for loading components within pages on a Magnolia CMS website. It is showing an intermittent issue where some javascript files fail to load, as shown in the image, and then that prevents the remaining components that use Angular on the page from loading.

[image]

Comment: it looks like its cache issues, did you try navigating to the page under incognito mode ? is it working then ?

Comment: Yes I also think it is cache issues. Site loads after in Incognito mode / clearing cache. Do you know how we can prevent this from happening for end users?